# How do I fix the positioning css

Tags: css

I'm working on my website: http://www.redties.co.uk/ and I was wondering how to fix the positioning of the icons on the right to make them inside the header just like the menu on the left. The class name is .header_inner_left.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please prodive a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Linking to a page that "doesn't work" will not help future readers of your question (who might be looking for similar answers) if the page in question actually works after you've fixed it.

Comment: If this is already done for the header on the left, it should be easier for you to refer it and replicate it on the right. Please try and do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- add `right: 0;` on `.q_logo img`
- add `left: auto` and `right: 0` on `header .container_inner .header_inner_left`

...and you'll have what you want.

Comment: thanks but I want it over the the right hand side of the container if you know what I mean.